# Сортировка списка без использования встроенных функций

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка, список

Дали задание отсортировать числа в списке без встроенных функции **sort**, **max** и **sorted**. И нужно использовать функцию данную ниже.
Пытался выполнить это вот таким способом, но не получилось:

```
def max_num(num):
    j = 0
    for i in num:
        if j < i:
            j = i
    return j

def min_num(num):
    h = 1
    for i in num:
        if h > i:
            h = i
    return h

lst = [2,235,654,4346,754,32,1]
k = max_num(lst)
g = min_num(lst)
spisok = lst[g:k]
print(spisok)
print(g, k)
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - еще не существует такого алгоритма сортировки который бы писался без циклов 
2 - функции минимума и максимума возвращают значения массива а не индексы к которым вы потом обращаетесь 
Вам нужно использовать сортировку минимумом (когда берется минимальный элемент и вставляется в начало списка) и так для всех n чисел. Информации по этому виду сортировки очень много, здесь вряд ли помогут лучше, чем готовая статья и код, которые легко найти.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь что ни будь найти)